# Is there any way to detect javascript postmessages using chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, postmessage

Does anybody sees a way to listen to cross iframe/window communication that is being done using the javascript postMessages ?

Best would be using the chrome.debugger in the background page of an extension. I see that I can listen to HTTP-Traffic using the "Network.requestWillBeSent" and "Network.responseReceived" events. But I would like also to listen to the internal communication on the page.

If my question isn't clear enough, please let me know, I'll try to clarify it more.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and bind a `message` event listener.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try this out and report back. (Still beginning with chrome extensions :))

Comment: @RobW _Avoid answering in comments!_ Could you make this into an answer, now that it's confirmed to be working?

Comment: @Xan Done. I was expecting someone else to pass by and write a more detailed answer, but it turns out that the single-line "answer" suffices.

Comment: @RobW I always feel bad expanding on a comment-answer by someone else - I'm robbing them of the dibs on the solution. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Xan Don't worry, if the comment-answerer wanted to take credit for the answer, then they should've posted an answer. If you really feel uncomfortable with using the ideas of a comment, you could refer to the original comment in your answer. In my view, it doesn't matter who posts the answer, as long as the OP and future readers get what they need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and bind a `message` event listener. This event listener will then be invoked [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) is called.